# How to use dict append nested dict in tcl

Tags: dictionary, nested, append, tcl

I want to have a nested dictionary in Tcl, and append a value.
But the nesting does not really work...
See code:

```
> set k [dict create]
> dict append k fee foo " kak"
> dict append k fee foo " poached"
> puts [dict get  [dict get $k fee] foo ]<code>
```

The result is:

```
missing value to go with key
    while executing
"dict get  [dict get $k fee] foo "
    invoked from within
"puts [dict get  [dict get $k fee] foo ]"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way to do it:

```
set k [dict create fee {foo {}}]
dict with k fee {append foo " kak"}
dict with k fee {append foo " poached"}
puts [dict get $k fee foo]
```

The `dict with` commands lets you use variable aliases for members of the dictionary (as long as they already exist, hence the initialization in the first line). One or more keys can be given before the script, to find the dictionary level where you want the changes to happen. Changing the value of the variable `foo` will now change the value of the key `fee foo` in `k`.

You can do it this way too, of course:

```
set k [dict create fee {foo {}}]
dict with k fee {
    append foo " kak"
    append foo " poached"
}
puts [dict get $k fee foo]
```

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that you are creating the dict correctly:

```
% set k [dict create]
% dict append k fee {foo " kak"}
fee {foo " kak"}
% dict append k fee {foo " poached"}
fee {foo " kak"foo " poached"}
```

Already here you can see that this is probably not what you're looking for. If you allow me to quote part of the docs:

> **dict append** *dictionaryVariable key ?string ...?*
>
> This appends the given string (or strings) to the value that the given key maps to in the dictionary value contained in the given variable, writing the resulting dictionary value back to that variable. [...]

To create a `dict` with multiple depths, I would use something like that, if I had to follow your method as close as possible:

```
% set k [dict create]
% dict append k fee {foo kak}
fee {foo kak}
% dict set k fee foo "[dict get $k fee foo] poached"
fee {foo {kak poached}}
```

If you want to append `poached` to the value of the string `kak`, you'll need to use `dict set` which allows you to modify values in a dict of any depth, which is a shortcoming of `dict append`. Now `dict get $k fee foo` (which does the same as `[dict get [dict get $k fee] foo]`) will give you `kak poached`.

I would however probably create the dictionary as:

```
set k [dict create foo {fee {kak poached}}]
```